# Regex to validate against URL

Tags: javascript, regex

We have regex to validate URL. I need a regex that will validate against it. Kindly help me in this.

URL for proper validation

var regexp = /(ftp|http|https)://(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(/|/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!-/]))?/

What's for validating against, i.e it should not be a URL.

Comment: Thanks, but this checks if it is a URL. I want to check if it is not a URL. Right opposite.

Comment: @AnushaSwaminathan That's what the !-operator is for...

Comment: Thanks, how do i do it. I'm new to js..

Comment: When you do your Regex validation, instead of `if([function you use to check])`, just write `if(![function you use to check])`. The ! (not operator) negates whatever boolean value you check for, True becomes false and false becomes true. I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a new regex.. I was not advised to negate completely.

Answer (score 0):

Just negate the regex using negative lookahead,

```
^(?!^((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)$).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/3)